# How does one explain the non-integral number of comparisons in min-max by divide and conquer?

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, minmax

For the naïve way, min-max compares `2n-2` times, where as for the divide and conquer way, it compares `(3/2)n-2` times. That is exactly (1/2)n comparison less. How does one explain (1/2) comparison? I am entirely lost (I don't even know if my interpretation is wrong). Please help

Comment: What are you talking about? min-max and divide-and-conquer are methods/algorithms to solve problems, comparisons are not a basic brick of them...

Comment: The question is not about basic bricks or building blocks, it's actually very straightforward. I guess you misread the question :)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, And don't forget that the very reason of using divide and conquer to find min-max numbers is to lower the comparisons. Whenever you can't reduce the complexity any further, always reduce the number of comparisons is what I have usually heard

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem: are you trying to get the min and max element of an array? Or are you talking about the minmax algorithm (theory of games)?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms_max_min_problem.htm This is what I'm talking about

Comment: And the theory of games, that is minImax algorithm (min - I - max) and not minmax

Comment: Minimax (sometimes MinMax), sorry but in my neighbourhood we are always using minmax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide and conquer approach (tournament) gives **exactly** `(3/2)n-2` comparisons when `n` is power of two (2,4,8,16...). Note in this case `(3/2)n-2` is integer.

For other values of `n` exact number of comparisons is slighly higher (consider simple cases of 4,5,6,7 items)

I think this formula is found using recurrence solving like `T(n) -...` - in this case usually you cannot expect precise values.

---

Also pairwise-comparison method exists - it provides `(3/2)n-2` comparison operations for even `n` and `(3/2)(n+1)-2` comparison operations for odd `n` values